# How to wrap / bend an object

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow, bezier-curves

[image: bracelet object]

So the above will be a bracelet, and I want it to wrap downwards symmetrically (as around a wrist / arm). I've tried a bunch of different things, and have gotten pretty close using the curve deform modifier.

I read up on how to use it, which is why the origin of the path is on it's first point and not in the center (otherwise the mesh leaps to line up to the left.

[image: deformed with a curve modifier]

However, as you can see in front view, this drags my whole mesh to the right instead of staying locked around the Y axis for a nice symmetrical bend. I feel like there's probably something obvious that I'm missing but I can't find the answer anywhere - something to do with the origin maybe?

Or if you know of a better way of doing this then I'm all ears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to curve my mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use the Simple deform modifier.
Add a bezier circle. Select the bracelet and go to the modifiers tab. Add a Simple deform modifier. Set it to bend and set the origin to the bezier circle. The bracelet will bend over the bezier circle's local Z axis, so you will have to rotate the circle. To get the result in the image below, I rotated the circle 90° around the global X axis. If I misinterpreted your description, you may have to rotate the circle differently. Once it bends the way you want it, change the angle. In the image below, I used 360°.

[image]

Note: I deleted the modifiers you had, except the subsurf. I did this for my convenience. I take it the curve modifier you had was the one you were using to get the bracelet to bend. If so, you should delete it. The order between the simple deform you already have and the one I'm suggesting makes a difference, and you will have to try to see which you want. You can change the order in which they are calculated by clicking the up and down arrows in the upper right corner of each modifier's config dialog.

Comment: @Phil I realise I may have misunderstood you completely. I assumed you wanted a circular shape (that's simply how I think about bracelets). If the shape with sharp angles is what you're after, this answer will not help you, because the simple deform always curves along a circle. The origin object only defines the axis to bend over. I will leave this answer here, in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: actually this was perfect, I was definitely looking for a curved shape, and this does the trick. I knew there was something big that I was overlooking - Thanks for your help!