# How to curve my mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

I'd like to curve my object, but I'm considering two options.

The first one is to make the object up with lots of vertices, like a sphere can be. The second is to apply some kind of modifier curve to a straight mesh, as I've understood there is such a possibility.

Here's an awesome pen drawing of what I'd like to achieve:

[image: Super cool curvy screen boomerang to throw at people]

and here's my current even more awesome result:

[image: current totally not curved render]

Rather non-awesomely, they don't quite match. So if someone would kindly point me to the correct method to achieving a nice-looking solution with relatively low polygons, I'd be much enlightened

Comment: Some answers to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21698/2217) may help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Add some  extra vertical loopcuts in your mesh, then select the middle loopcut. Turn on the proportional editing tool (<kbd>O</kbd>) in edit mode and select the sphere falloff, then grab (<kbd>G</kbd>) it over the axis (in my case the Y). Make sure the proportional size is bigger than the object (scroll your mousewheel).You will see a circle that is the proportional size. After that you can add a subdivision modifier.

Comment: That got me this: http://imgur.com/RsMLulu. Still some work to do, but much further thanks to your technique :)

Comment: Can I do this with UVs?

Answer (score 25):

There are four basic ways to bend your object.

1. Destructively editing it in edit mode
2. A [Curve modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/curve.html)
3. A [Simple Deform modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html)
4. A [Lattice modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) (or Mesh Deform modifier, they work nearly the same)

All have their pros and cons, I will briefly list them here.

**Modeling in edit mode**
Moving the edges and vertices in edit mode to make the curve, is sometimes the least desirable. After you have bent or curved your object, there is no turning back - it is now permanently curved.  The plus side is that there is no extra work, just select some edges and hit <kbd>G</kbd>. For a smoother edit, press <kbd>O</kbd> to enable [Proportional Editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional) and use the mouse wheel to set the radius for the tool

**The curve modifier**, where the mesh is bent using a bezier or nurbs curve, is over kill for such a simple curve. While it works well, you will probably spend more time setting up the curve object, then you would using other methods.

**The simple deform modifier**, explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34601/2217), really is the best solution for your particular situation. There is no quicker or simpler way to make a shape like you want.

**The lattice modifier**, is extremely powerful. While it can do much more then a simple bend, I think it works quite well in this situation.

1. Add a Lattice object around the text (scale it in object mode to fit the text)
2. Add a *Lattice* modifier to the object and put in the name of the new lattice.
3. in edit mode, edit the lattice so that it bends way you want (this part is very similar to the first method).

[image: lattice settings]

---

[image: difference in the methods]
Do note that there is a difference between the methods in the way the edges look.

#### [Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/375/)

That blend shows the four methods explained above.

Comment: wow. Only if every answer was like this.

Comment: See also this related post: [How to bend a plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147404)

Answer (score 11):

To curve your mesh I would suggest to use the **SimpleDeform (Bend) modifier**.

[image]

Using a modifier will not help you to lower the number of polygons of you object.

Maybe can help you to decide in an interactive way the resolution of your curve, but the final geometry will have the same number of polygons as if it was created by starting from a sphere's edge loop.

[image]
[image]
[image]

A bigger number of transversal edge loops allows a higher resolution of the curve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great method @Carlo Bergonzini! I don't know why, but somehow it works well for me only if I set the Empty as an origin point. Please see the screenshots: https://imageshack.com/i/exl1uY0Rj

Comment: I'm probably still missing something, but I get weird results. http://imgur.com/ZfSKNCj http://imgur.com/vDYfuSS

Comment: Apply the scale and the rotation. Modifiers act before the object transformations. @Gonzou

Comment: @Carlo Bergonzini Thanks for a tip, works perfect now :).

Comment: For anyone getting weird results: try rotating your Empty 90-deg on one of its axes (for me it was the Z axis that fixed it, your results may vary depending on your scene).

Comment: The Bend happens around the local Z-Axis of the origin object.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that quickly with Warp tool.

Make sure the cursor is located in the center of the object hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut, move the mouse to get the desired angle and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> button to disable bending clamp so the object bends on both sides of the cursor.

Note: Initial position of the mouse relative to the 3D cursor and the viewing angle can give different results.

[image]

Comment: I experimented with your technique a bit, though it never gives me the symmetrical result. Maybe I should warp only a half of a mesh and then use the Mirror Modifier?

Comment: @Gonzou Yes there is no precise control with this tool, but to make it work symmetrical the initial position of the mouse should be exactly on the x axis, if its done from the view like in my screenshot.

Comment: I think the best way to use this tool is shown by cegaton here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21707/2217

Comment: This can't work. Even in perfect orthographic views the Bend tool (not Warp, shift-w is Bend) cannot do equal distance bending - it WILL deform the outer edges inequally between left and right.