# Freestyle is not exporting with the object

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, export, freestyle

## Here is what it looks like in Blender Render (Not Cycles).

[image: Blender Render Image]

---

## This is how I set it up.

[image: Setup Image]

---

#### Basically, I'm trying to export it, but it's not including the "Freestyle" lines.

#### When I open up the .dae file in Finder, it looks like this:

[image: Finder Image Exported]

---

What is wrong here? I want it to be exported (COLLIDA .dae) with the black outline. I'm seeming to think that maybe the "Freestyle" is *only* for the Blender Render. Am I right? How would I go about getting the black outline included in my exported model? Is it an export setting I have to tick?

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: [Freestyle](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/render/freestyle/introduction.html#what-is-freestyle) is a rendering engine: it "takes pictures" of the object, but doesn't affect the geometry of the model. The lines exist only in the picture. You should perhaps look for the Wireframe modfier or something like this.

Comment: Oh. Then refer to the end of my question. How would I go about creating this black outline?

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/562/19287

Comment: Original Question before: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50119/2843, related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49235/2843

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments the cartoon-style black outline is an image only effect done internally in post production over the rendered image, it does not affect the model nor is it part of the geometry, there fore it cannot be exported in any file format other than a rendered image, or at best as an SVG vector file (using the *Freestyle SVG Exporter* addon), you can then place over your image.

Where are you exporting your model in COLLADA too? Some Game engine? Other modelling application? You will most likely need to recreate the outline effect there in the destination software.

Otherwise if you actually want to have it in-model with actual geometry there are a few other options.

- Either us a wireframe modifier over your objects to construct a cage-like structure over you mesh
- Use a Bevel modifier on your mesh with a material index offset
  [image]
- Manually bevel your geometry and assign different materials
- UV Unwrap your model and use an image texture, created in an external image editing software with the desired black edges in the correct places along the edges.

Comment: I am exporting to Xcode (which can be considered a game engine).

Comment: Well I don't know XCode but you either need to recreate the effect there using the available shaders or materials, or if you need it at the geometry level use one of the above options