# How to create outlines for objects so that the outlines stays when the file is exported as DAE format?

Tags: mesh, objects, export

I would like to know how to create outlines for the objects created in Blender and make sure the outlines actually shows up when the file is exported into DAE format.

TIA!

Comment: Hello. Could you illustrate a bit more what are outlines here ? If they are meshes, they can be exported in dae.

Comment: Please see if the answers provided here are valid for your situation http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/freestyle-is-not-exporting-with-the-object/50215#50215

Comment: @David, amazing for me... how can you know we are talking about freestyle here ?

Comment: @lemon freestyle is not the focus of this question but, both are asking how to export a mesh so outlines will show up.

Comment: @David Seems like this could be a case of http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am still not clear of how to create the outlines you mentioned in your answer to the other question. Is there a more simple way than the ones you mentioned?

Comment: As far as I know there are no other methods, those are quite simple to use actually, mostly modifier based only. Check the blender manual on how to use the [Bevel Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html) and the [Wireframe Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html) . If you have any further questions please post a new question.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the information. I have figured out how to use the wireframe modifier to add the outline to the mesh object.

Comment: I'm glad it helped