# Bending an object?

Tags: modeling

How would I go about bending this object?

[image]

[image]

Comment: bending can be done with the "simple deform" or "curve" modifier, but be aware that the mesh geometry need to have the good edges to be bound with a good result

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated my post as well. What do you mean by good edges?