# How do I make a curved arrow?

Tags: modeling

I have a simple arrow like this:

[image]

I want to make it curved about the Z axis like this:

[image]

In this image it is a texture applied with transparent background to a plane. But I want to make it a 3D model and apply a special material.

I tried adding a curve modifier and ended up with this:

[image]

What is the best method to use?

Comment: Using the curve is ok. But you have to subdivide your mesh (mainly transversally to the curve) in order to allow it to follow the curve.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34616/2217 But like lemon said you need more geometry. The mesh can only bend on edges, and you only have one edge in the arrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have stated, I need to add more geometry to deform[image] around the curve:

[image]