# Bending sharply for edges of cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

This may have been answered in another post but I quickly skimmed over the answers there and they didn't look like they would help

I'm making a bow but I'm struggling with the string. I'd like the ends of the string to fold inwards.

Right now it's doing this.
[image]

But I'd like it to do something like this in the one mesh
[image]

I've subdivided it once but I haven't made much progress with that. Is there something I'm missing or should I subdivide it more? I've also tried to use armatures but it just isn't working for me.

Comment: What do you mean "ends of the string to fold inwards"? If you want to prevent ends of the string going through the bow then just grab vertices in the endings slightly inwards or scale the string a bit down

Comment: My intent is for the string to go in a dent in the bow, but I'm struggling with bending it in general.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh