# How do I make it so that my mesh has the same curve as another mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Sorry if the title is misleading. I really dont know how to ask this properly so I'll add a lot of pictures to try to explain.

I'm trying to recreate Excalibur, and I'm stuck at this for a while. I'll call the blade mesh 1. I'll call the crest (flat mesh) mesh 2. I want mesh 2 to "bend", or let's say "wrap" around the mesh 1. So, it will be the same thickness and its gonna bend around the blade. Here's some pics, and I'll also leave the .blend file if I still couldnt explain well :/

I know this is a question board, but if you download the blend file, I would be very happy if you give me some feedback.

Photos:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

[image]

In picture 3, the top one is the flat mesh, and below that one is the "curve" that I want it to bend around.

Comment: If I get what you want add Curve modifier to "Flat" mesh and make "curve* mesh as curve (either converting via Alt+C or creating Shift+A>Curve). After matching origin points flat mesh will be bent along curve. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh

Comment: Thanks, I made a Bezier Curve and I curved it around. I have a question though. Positions in edit mode and object mode is different now. When I re-position my mesh properly in object mode, in edit mode it positions itself different. When I re-position my mesh in edit mode, in object mode it position itself different again. Can I fix this?

Comment: Okay, I applied the curve and it fixed it. Thanks for all the help.