# Modelling which is the easiest way to curve a face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I would like to bend in a curve the 2 faces you see in this cube?

I know I can subdivide and move the vertices in a curve but is there a way to curve a line between 2 vertices?

[image: desired faces to be curved selected]

Comment: I don't think so, you could give your object a Subsurf then bend it with a Mesh Deform but it would make it round

Comment: A line with two points can't be both a line and a curve.  Your question is ambiguous.   Please describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can add some loopcuts and then use proportional editing with a sharp falloff to scale it into a nice curve. Notice how changing the radius and falloff type of the proportional editing tool completely changes how the vertices are deformed.(If none of the preset falloffs are good enough, you can make a custom curve to create the exact shape you want).

[image: gif]

Comment: Custom curve? How would you do that?

Comment: I know you can create custom falloff curves for things like the Warp Modifier, but on proportional editing?

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few ways to bend or curve a mesh. Speaking just in edit mode there is the [Warp tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/warp.html), the [Bend tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/bend.html), [Proportional Editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html), etc.
(To curve an entire object I have an [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34616/2217) that outlines a few different methods.)

No matter what tool you choose to model this, you are going to need more geometry. There is nothing that can make a curve from one face.

I see you are going for a low poly feel. Knowing that you might want to consider triangles, instead of loops going all the way around.
[image: triangle filled faces]
Now on to how to make the curved faces.

### Simply a Cylinder

Even with all the fancy tools, I still sometimes prefer to add a circle (or cylinder) and use half of it for the curved part, it's simple and easy. In the image below I added one loopcut through center so that the triangle fan would line up (else the topology would look like the image above.) With the object in this state it is a simple matter of <strike>[removing doubles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles)</strike> [merging by distance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merge-by-distance) to combine the new piece.
[image: half cylinder for rounded end]

---

### Loop Cut and Slide

One interesting way to curve the end face is to use the smooth feature of the [Loop Cut and Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#loop-cut-and-slide) tool. Start by deleting the connecting faces on the top and bottom (so the loops stay on the end face). Then simply add loops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and adjust the smoothness in the  *Adjust Last Operation* panel.
[image: Loop Cut and Slide smooth]

---

### Spin tool

You could use the [Spin tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html) to create the new curved faces. With the corner edge selected (circled in red in the image below) initiate the spin tool, and adjust the *Angle* and *Steps* to your liking.
[image: spin tool]

---

### Proportional Editing

First added more geometry to the end face. Select the top and bottom edge of that face, Subdivide it and bump the *Number of Cuts* up to 5 or so. Now select the center most edge of the newly created edges, and with Proportional Editing enabled and set to *Sphere* move that edge out.
[image: animated gif showing Subdividing a face and moving an edge with Proportional Editing]

PS use a mirror modifier. No need to duplicate work when both sides of the object are the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the curve to pass through a set of known points, the shipped add-on *Loop Tools > Curve* will make a cubic (or a linear) interpolation for you..

[image]

- Original
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> cut loops
- Move vertices to known points on edge loops, select them, (and not the others)
- Call *Loop Tools > Curve* to do the interpolation