# How to add a curve into this ōdachi?

Tags: mesh

I am wondering if there is any way to add a curve to this ōdachi I made without having to go into the mesh and add it manually, since it'll be very painstakingly difficult to do it manually.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Sword]

Comment: It has been updated

Comment: Use proportional editing, or a curve modifier, or simple deform. Read the following link: [how to curve my mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh)

Comment: Sadly none of these helped since the mesh of the sword was pretty broken, so I ended up manually making the blade part over again and then weight painted it to curve. Thank you for the suggestions though!