# how to bend straight faces to make a curve

Tags: objects

I would like to bend this part, so it looks like a nice curve. But instead it is grabbing this whole part.
I added a curve on picture, so that it is easier to understand what I want to achieve as a result. Bend this part alongside with curve

Here is a file to better understand my issue
[image]

Thank you very much for your help
[image]

Comment: if you would like for others to work with your exact file (for this or future questions), you can use this [service link of Giant Cow Films](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  - drag your file in and the insert your link to the post in the input field before clicking the upload button. You can then connect your file with the post so others have your exact file to work on.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, i hope that I have done it correctly     [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7SloAoYl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7SloAoYl/)

Comment: Almost there: When you uploaded the file, the last step is to copy the provided embed code as [explained here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help) and add it to your post (not the comment) (edit your original post, then you can add the snippet). Then your file will show up represented by an icon to download for others.

Comment: thank you once more :D

Comment: You can select the middle edge and using the proportional editing tool pull the edge out until it looks how you want it to. To get a smoother curve you should add more loop cuts.

Comment: there is a lot of information on this site . You should use the search function https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh

Comment: thank you very much for assistance. Now and so on I will try to do more research here, before posting my question

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways (as always) to try and get what you want to achieve.

To prepare I rotated the Mesh 90° around the X axis and applied the rotation. So we can watch it from Orthograpic Top View while editing (I just prefer that).

1. Like @AntonPg suggested:

   - Go into Edit Mode
   - Select the middle Edge
   - Activate Proportional Editing (experiment with the settings ..)
   - Press *G* and then *Shift + Z* to move the selected Edge only on the X and Y axis (without Z axis). Then move and adjust the proportional editing influence radius (MouseWheel).

[image]